# Azure search null value for GeoSpatial object

Tags: geospatial, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I created an Azure Search Index from CosmosDB which has a location data.

```
public Point GeoLocation { get; set; }
```

when I set this to null the indexer throws below error and does not index anything.

```
"errorMessage": "Value '' is not a valid GeoJson point."
```

Is there an empty/null value for `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point` that does not cause an error for this case?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the flow of data? Specifically, where is Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial.Point being used? I'm guessing that you're using it as a model class to define the format of your documents in CosmosDB, then using an Azure Search indexer to index the documents -- is that correct?

Comment: @BruceJohnston yes that s correct.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I've asked for help from the indexer experts on my team to investigate.

Comment: This is unexpected. We'll need some more details from you to figure out what's going on. Please email me at bruce dot johnston at microsoft and I'll put you in touch with the engineers investigating this.